# How to create a jQuery function to return a bool?

Tags: jquery

How can I create a jQuery function like

```
$.MyFunction(/*optional parameter*/)?
```

which will return a bool?

**note:**

I've tried this:

```
jQuery.fn.isValidRequest = function (options) {

    return true;
}

// I'm contending with Prototype, so I have to use this    
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {    

    // and jQuery 1.2.6, supplied by the client - long story
    $('a').livequery('click', function () {

        alert($.isValidRequest("blah"));
        return false;
    });
});
```

but it crashes on the alert() with

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

**This is what worked in the end:**

```
jQuery.isValidRequest = function (options) {

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wait - you have two versions of jQuery active at once? What symbols are you using to differentiate between them? Or do you just mean that you're using jQuery 1.2.6 for this.

Comment: If you're defining your function in `$.fn`, Then you'll need to call it there `$.fn.isValidRequest("blah")` or from a jQuery object `$('selector').isValidRequest()`. Doesn't seem like that's what you want. If it is just more of a utility, then define it under `jQuery` as in `jQuery.isValidRequest = function(...`.

Comment: @Shog9 - I think OP was explaining (in the code comment) why he's using `livequery` instead of `live()`. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @patrick: you may be right. Good catch on the $.fn vs $. scenario... I tend to forget that people *use* the latter.

Comment: @patrick, @Shog: yeah, I'm using 1.2.6. That's why I need livequery. Also, the client has Prototype in the HTML wrapper they supply us with, into which we inject our content.

Comment: @Dave: got it. And updated the answer to reflect patrick's observation (gotta ask though, why bother attaching this function to $)?

Comment: @Shog, just to see what was involved. I got it working with the suggestions from this comment thread, and the answer below, though it's a little different from what's in the answer so I'll update the question with what I have. Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a function you intend to call from jQuery *instances*, you'd define it like this:

```
$.fn.MyFunction = function(options)
{
  // return bool here
};
```

And call like any other jQuery method:

```
$('selector').MyFunction(...);
```

A function intended to be called from the global jQuery object (or its $ alias) would be attached directly to that object:

```
$.MyFunction = function(options)
{
  // return bool here
};
```

And call the same way:

```
$.MyFunction(...);
```

Note that I've used $.fn for brevity - this can cause problems if jQuery is prevented from using the $ alias for compatibility with other libraries. The recommended way to attach a plugin function is:

```
(function($) // introduce scope wherein $ is sure to equate to jQuery
{ 
  $.fn.MyFunction = function(options) 
  { 
    // return bool here 
  };
})(jQuery); // conclude plugin scope
```

Note also that most jQuery functions return `this`, to enable chaining; if you opt to return some other value, you'll be unable to do this. Be sure to document clearly that your function returns a boolean, or you'll find yourself wondering why e.g. `$("...").MyFunction().hide()` breaks later on.

You can read more about extending jQuery here:
[Extending jQuery – plugin development](http://tech.ovaistariq.net/2010/07/extending-jquery-plugin-development/)
and in the jQuery documentation:
[Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: Style note: by using $.fn instead of jQuery.fn, you'll introduce errors if $ is used by some other library (via [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)).

Comment: i had used $ for bravity's sake, the recommended way is 

(function($)
{
  $.fn.MyFunction = function(options)
  {
    // return bool here
  }
})(jQuery);

Comment: This doesn't work.. I've updated the question to reflect, thanks

Comment: fair enough - I've taken the liberty of adding your comment and portions of my own answer to this answer, as there are rather too many answers here already.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.MyFunction = function(param) {
   if(arguments.length > 0)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/basil/archive/2008/09/22/defining-your-own-functions-in-jquery.aspx

You can still just return like in plain JavaScript true/false for boolean parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.myfunction(options){
return options.isThisTrue;
}
```

usage:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){ 
         var isThisTrue = $.myfunction({isthisTrue: false});
         // isThisTrue is false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

$.fn.MyFunction = function(params) { return true; }